# REST call between two Web Applications on Same Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I have two Web Applications on the same SharePoint Farm, intranet.company.com and associates.company.com

I'm trying to pull user data with a REST call from the intranet site like this:

```
https://intranet.company.com/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.w%7CDOMAIN%5CUsername%27
```

This works when calling from intranet web application just fine.

BUT not if I am calling it from the associates web application.  The error is:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

I don't want to use Visual Studio to install an app to get an AppContextSite reference.  Is there a way to bypass this, perhaps a server setting in IIS on the farm?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like CORS isn't set up properly on your server. CORS allows rest calls to make cross domain calls.